# How i add javax.media.jai.* package in project?

Tags: java, jmf, jai

I read the posts and download the cross platform ZIP file which contain jmf.jar file.
But this jar does not contain only javax.media.jai package.
where i get this jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using maven. Here is the maven repo...
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.media/jai_core/1.1.3

Or download the source from here
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html

Comment: Thank u very much... its what i want

Comment: The former, the mvn dependency, does not exist.  At the latter, the oracle link, the version 1.1.3 is not present.  Perhaps at one point the answer was correct, but it currently is not.

Comment: @demongolem the maven dep still looks like it is there. But in general I think the answer still holds up even if you may need to find a new version on maven.

Comment: It's August 2023 and the linked Maven repository only has the javadoc and the .pom file, the actual `jai-core-1.1.3.jar` is missing. You can still get the "codec" for version 1.1.3 [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.media/jai-codec/1.1.3) (looks like it's a 3rd party site though) but without the "core" it's of no use.